# How to add no auto rehash option in nodejs mariadb connector?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, loopbackjs

When i connect to maridb using command line, it takes lot of time to load all the database schema and tables (roughly 10 minuntes). However, adding -A argument in command line saves the time and connection is made instantly.

Now when i want to connect to mariadb server via nodejs connector, i am constantly getting timeout error. Is there any way i can add no-auto-rehash option in connection options? Have tried a lot of things, but to no success. Need resolution for the same

Comment: Node.js connector doesn't have autocompletion, or things like that. If you have a timeout issue, it would be better to analyze the connection parameter (good host, port, set a greater connectTimeout (in ms) ...)